# Java EE - IntelliJ - javax.persistence.Table - table name cannot be resolved

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea

I am trying to resolve this problem since 3 days, I cannot solve it. I read about, that IntelliJ is mixing up something. I found that thread and similar answers in other threads, and tried to to exactly the same, but it did not work: [Cannot resolve column 'USERNAME' less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32660977/cannot-resolve-column-username-less)

My Persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="NewPersistenceUnit">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>Book</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"></property>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"></property>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My class Book where I want to set the name. The Table "Book" cannot be resolved.

```
 @Entity    
 @Table(name = "BOOK")
        public class Book implements Serializable{

            @Id
            private int id;

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what the answer you posted, in the persistence tool window 
(view -> tool windows -> persistence), you should see persistence.xml, right click and select "assign data source" and assign your configured datasource.

More info here: [My Favorited Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14356148/intellij-idea-specify-datasource-for-jpa-validation)

Comment: How can I check, if my Data Source is correctly configured? I remember, that it once worked, but I have never configured my Data Source. Suddenly, I don't know how, it stopped working.

Comment: click on view -> tool windows -> database, right click on your database -> properties.  Then there will be a "Test Connection" button.  If it is configured properly, it should say "Connection Successful", if it's not configured properly it will throw an exception.

Comment: Connection successful... I think my hibernate is not integrated the proper way, but I set up everything with hibernate. The weird think is, that if i put         `<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>` to my `persistence.xml`, it tells me that `jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider` cannot be resolved.

Comment: another thing to try that I just noticed is, you are just using "Book" in persistence.xml  You need to use the fully qualified name, like com.mycompany.Book

Comment: I don't have a package name, but I also tried to create a package name and do it like you have told. No changes...